# Excel: Compare string between 2 columns, if match, trim/delete the matched string

Tags: excel

I am not good at advanced Excel formula and need help with data cleanup in excel for migration purpose. This is my scenario:

```
Column A                                             Column B 

DocName                                              EmployeeName 
ACCT6789_John_Smith_ACCOUNT_DOC_25_JAN_2007          John_Smith
ACCT1122_Jane_Doe_ACCOUNT_DOC_EID00022_21_DEC_2009   Jane_Doe
ACCT1462_Phil_Morris_ACCOUNT_DOC_EID0252             Phil_Moris
```

I need ColumnA's string to find exact match against ColumnB. If matched, then delete that matched string from ColumnA. If no exact match, there will be no action and the script will continue checking the next row. I know there will be issue with double underscore, and I hope to only have one underscore between any 2 words.

The desired results for example above will be:

```
ACCT6789_ACCOUNT_DOC_25_JAN_2007              John_Smith 
ACCT1122_ACCOUNT_DOC_EID00022_21_DEC_2009     Jane_Doe
ACCT1462_Phil_Morris_ACCOUNT_DOC_EID0252      Phil_Moris
```

Comment: Could you try to format your column description as "code" (curly braces in the edit box) - it is hard to see what you are doing...

Comment: I upload a screenshot for easy view, but somehow it doesn't show. Let me reupload again.

Comment: I fixed the formatting for you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using just formulas in the spreadsheet, you can do the following:

Assume that column C is available (if not, find an empty column). Type this formula in row 1 (if you have headers in row 1, type it in the first available row and adjust the `1` to the row number):

```
=FIND(B1, A1)
```

This will find an occurrence of `B1` ("John Doe") in `A1` `("ACCT6789_John_Smith_ACCOUNT_DOC_25_JAN_2007")`

In the next column over, you type

```
=LEFT(A1, C1-1) & RIGHT(A1, LEN(a1) - C1 - LEN(B1))
```

This takes "the bit of A1 before the string we found" plus "the bit after the thing we found".

Now copy this formula all the way down (select both C1 and D1, then double clicking the little box in the bottom right hand corner is a shortcut to dragging all the way down...). Column D now has the results you want.

Finally, to copy them back to column A, select all of column D, hit copy, then do a Paste-Special-Values into column A. Finally, delete Columns C and D.

By the way - this method assumes there are underscores on either side of the name you found, and will actually remove the trailing one. If you can't be sure of that, you should change the formula in Column D to

```
=LEFT(A1, C1-1) & RIGHT(A1, LEN(a1) - C1 - LEN(B1) + 1)
```

And then do another round to remove double underscores and replace them with single... It sounds to me like you don't need that, though.

Comment: Hi, following the formula for both C1 and D1, I get the value "8" for C1 and "ACCT6789_ACCOUNT_DOC_25_JAN_2007" for D1, which is correct (Thanks!). However on the next step, when I selected both C1 and D1 then copy the formula down, all column C & D values are exactly as C1 and D1 (even though the formula already pointing to A2-B2, A3-B3, etc.

Comment: You may need to "recalculate" (if it is set to "manual"). Try pressing <ctrl><alt><shift>-F9 to force a recalculation of "everything"... Should only need to do this once. Under File->Options->Formulas there is a section "Calculation options". I am guessing it is set to "Manual"...

Comment: You are the guru! It's working perfectly. 
Actually this is a simplify version of what we are looking for. The actual one is to match the long DocName against 3 different columns (Name, Acct# and Crt) and then delete all 3 matches if matched (trimming). If not much, can you help me with this more complex formula? It's ok if it takes too much of your time because I can run this one 3 times. Many thanks again.

Comment: It will take you less time to run it three times, than it will take me to write down instructions without having the actual spreadsheet. If you're happy, would you "accept" the answer? Click the little check mark - it will turn green.

Answer (score 0):

Though this thread is old but I took some code from another threads and tried and looks like solution is giving approx match. Here I am trying to match one column of sheet1 with one column of sheet2:

1. add command button in excel
2. put following code and click/run button and function gives you result in selected column

```vb
 Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()
     Dim ws As Worksheet
     Dim LRow As Long, i As Long, lval As String


   '~~> Change this to the relevant worsheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

With ws
    '~~> Find Last Row in Col G which has data
    LRow = .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    If LRow = 1 Then
        MsgBox "No data in column D"
    Else
        For i = 2 To LRow


             lval = "D"
            .Range("G" & i).Value = FuzzyFind(lval & i, .Range("PWC"))
        Next i
    End If
    End With

    End Sub


    Function FuzzyFind(lookup_value As String, tbl_array As Range) As String
    Dim i As Integer, str As String, Value As String
    Dim a As Integer, b As Integer, cell As Variant

    For Each cell In tbl_array
     str = cell
     For i = 1 To Len(lookup_value)
      If InStr(cell, Mid(lookup_value, i, 1)) > 0 Then
     a = a + 1
     cell = Mid(cell, 1, InStr(cell, Mid(lookup_value, i, 1)) - 1) & Mid   (cell, InStr(cell, Mid(lookup_value, i, 1)) + 1, 9999)
    End If
     Next i
     a = a - Len(cell)
     If a > b Then
       b = a
       Value = str
    End If
       a = 0
    Next cell
      If Value <> "" Then
         FuzzyFind = Value
      Else
         FuzzyFind = "None"
      End If
End Function
```